# Codeigniter: Model query doesn't retrieve any data

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my database I have fields that has value of

1 Blue White

2 White Blue

3 Blue

4 White

for every ids.

I have a controller where I declare $color="White Blue" and passed it on the model.
On my model I use 'explode' to separate the two words and use a for-each to extract.

Here's my model:

```
  public function test($color){

    $arry = explode(" ", $color); 

    foreach($arry as $colr){
    $this->db->where("tags like '%$colr%' or 
            tags like '%$colr'or 
            tags like '$colr%' ");
            }


    $q=$this->db->get('test');
    return $q;

    }
```

When I try to run it on localhost, it gives me Call to a member function result() error.
I know that this kind of error means it doesn't retrieve any data from my database. 
When I tried to put an error on my query, I found out that instead if using 'OR' 
after the first for-each it uses 'AND'. Do you have any idea on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1):

```
tags like '%$colr'or
```

is missing a space?

```
tags like '%$colr' or
```

Futhermore, putting the $colr between '%' should be sufficient. No need for the other lines.

So, this should do the trick:

```
public function test($color){

    $arry = explode(" ", $color); 

    foreach($arry as $colr){
      $this->db->where("tags like '%$colr%' "); 
    }

    $q=$this->db->get('test');
    return $q;

}
```

Comment: You need to use $this->db->or_where(); to join the where parts, otherwise it results as AND

Answer (score 1):

```
public function test($color){

    $arry = explode(" ", $color); 
    foreach($arry as $colr) $this->db->or_where("tags like '%$colr%' "); 
    $q=$this->db->get('test');
    return $q;

}
```

Comment: sir @jtheman,the $this->db->OR_WHERE() really help me :) but I was wondrin, is it really ok that the for-each have no '{brackets}'? Anyway, it really do the trick. thanks!  :)

Comment: If there is only one statement then no brackets needed! If you have two or more you need brackets (or alternate syntax with colon and endforeach (I use that all the time)...)